# How to databind edittext attribute android:enabled with viewmodel data?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-databinding, android-livedata

***Requirement:***
I have a usename and a password edittexts. I want password edittext to be enabled only when a valid username is entered in username edittext.

***Layout code:***

```
<variable
    name="model"
    type="com.app.viewmodel.ViewModel" />

...

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    ...>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/username_edit_text"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:onTextChanged="@{model::onUsernameTextChanged}"
        .../>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    ...>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/password_edit_text"
        android:enabled="@{safeUnbox(model.isUsernameValid)}"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:onTextChanged="@{model::onPasswordTextChanged}"
        .../>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

***Viewmodel:***

```
private val isUsernameValid: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData()

init {
    isUsernameValid.value = false
}

fun getIsUsernameValid(): MutableLiveData<Boolean> {
    return isUsernameValid
}

fun onUsernameTextChanged(usernameString: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
    isUsernameValid.value = (usernameString.length >= 8)

    Log.e(TAG, "${isUsernameValid.value}")
}
```

In the log message, I could see that the `isUsernameValid` is changed to true after entering valid username, but the password edittext is not enabling after that.

Any possible way to solve this?

Edit 1: After reading @Birju Vachhani 's solution.

***Fragment code:***

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

    if (activity != null) {
        signInViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SignInViewModel::class.java)
        signInFragmentBinding.sharedModel = mainActivityViewModel
        signInFragmentBinding.lifecycleOwner = this
        signInFragmentBinding.model = signInViewModel
    }
}
```

`signInFragmentBinding.lifecycleOwner = this` Adding this line solved it.

Comment: Not sure if isUsernameValid can be private here, because you reference to it in the xml

Comment: @P.Juni I have getters/setters and hence it can be private.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your activity, do this and it will work:

```
binding.lifecycleOwner = this
```

In order to make binding act on `LiveData` changes, `LifecyclerOwner` needs to be provided.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    ...

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding: ActivityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        binding.viewModel = viewModel
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Can you elaborate on the lifecycler owner? Or give links to any good related source.

Comment: All I can say is that LiveData is called LiveData because it is tightly bound to the lifecycle of the component that observes it. A LifecycleOwner is a class that has an Android lifecycle. These events can be used by custom components to handle lifecycle changes without implementing any code inside the Activity or the Fragment.

Comment: As we are binding LiveData to our view using DataBinding, bindings needs to know whether it is okay to execute those LiveData bindings and update the value or not. For that they need to be aware of the lifecycle of that component. In our case its activity view. That's why we provide LifecycleOwner so that databinding can dispatch updates to the bound LiveData components.